# App installation failed using push notification profile

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

While installing app to device using push notification enabled certificate got below error message.
    "This application or a bundle it contains has the same bundle identifier as this application or another bundle that it contains. Bundle identifiers must be unique."
    Pleas let me know if any one come across this problem.

Comment: It is clear from the message that more than bundle contain the same bundle ID.

Comment: I think there is another app with same bundle id install on that phone. Check it once!

Comment: There is no app installed with same bundle id

Answer (score 0):

**1. Bundle Identifier:** 
  According to Apple docs : A bundle identifier lets iOS and OS X recognize any updates to your app. Your bundle ID must be registered with Apple and be unique to your app. Bundle IDs are app-type specific (either iOS or OS X). The same bundle ID cannot be used for both iOS and OS X apps.

2. Apple Identifier screenshot.
   [image]

**Solution:** It is possible that you are using same bundle identifier, which is being used by another application. Kindly change your bundle identifier and make certificate accordingly.

3. Make sure follow some standard tutorial for making certificate for Push Notification.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

Happy Coding!

Comment: I had changed my app bundle identifier even after i got same error message.